# How to know if there're any Windows OS updates available for installation?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, updates

I'm curious if it's possible to find out if there are any updates for the Windows OS ready for installation?

PS. I need to find this out from a C++ service application.

Comment: just google for "windows api updates"

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Windows Update Agent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).